# Set ACL on Lambda Python MediaConvert Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-elemental

I'm using the following Python and json media convert job in order to run a AWS MediaConvert job. (original guide I followed is [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-simple-vod-workflow/blob/master/7-MediaConvertJobLambda/README.md)).

The ACL on the new files created by the MediaConvert Job should be `ACL: 'public-read'` however I'm unable to set this. I would prefer to assign this on the file rather than a bucket permission due to complexity in the folder structure on this bucket (I know there are no such things as true folders on S3).

**Convert.py**
    #!/usr/bin/env python

```
import glob
import json
import os
import uuid
import boto3
import datetime
import random
import urlparse

from botocore.client import ClientError

def handler(event, context):

    assetID = str(uuid.uuid4())
    sourceS3Bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    sourceS3Key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    sourceS3 = 's3://'+ sourceS3Bucket + '/' + sourceS3Key
    sourceS3Basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sourceS3))[0]
    destinationS3 = 's3://' + os.environ['DestinationBucket']
    destinationS3basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(destinationS3))[0]
    mediaConvertRole = os.environ['MediaConvertRole']
    region = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
    statusCode = 200
    body = {}

    # Use MediaConvert SDK UserMetadata to tag jobs with the assetID 
    # Events from MediaConvert will have the assetID in UserMedata
    jobMetadata = {'assetID': assetID}

    print (json.dumps(event))

    try:
        # Job settings are in the lambda zip file in the current working directory
        with open('job.json') as json_data:
            jobSettings = json.load(json_data)
            print(jobSettings)

        # get the account-specific mediaconvert endpoint for this region
        mc_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name=region)
        endpoints = mc_client.describe_endpoints()

        # add the account-specific endpoint to the client session 
        client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name=region, endpoint_url=endpoints['Endpoints'][0]['Url'], verify=False)

        # Update the job settings with the source video from the S3 event and destination 
        # paths for converted videos
        jobSettings['Inputs'][0]['FileInput'] = sourceS3

        S3KeyWatermark = 'encoded-video/mp4/' + sourceS3Basename
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][0]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyWatermark

        S3KeyThumbnails = 'encoded-video/poster/' + sourceS3Basename
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][1]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyThumbnails     

        print('jobSettings:')
        print(json.dumps(jobSettings))

        # Convert the video using AWS Elemental MediaConvert
        job = client.create_job(Role=mediaConvertRole, UserMetadata=jobMetadata, Settings=jobSettings)
        print (json.dumps(job, default=str))

    except Exception as e:
        print 'Exception: %s' % e
        statusCode = 500
        raise

    finally:
        return {
            'statusCode': statusCode,
            'body': json.dumps(body),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        }
```

**job.json**

```
{
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "CustomName": "MP4",
        "Name": "File Group",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "MP4",
              "Mp4Settings": {
                "CslgAtom": "INCLUDE",
                "FreeSpaceBox": "EXCLUDE",
                "MoovPlacement": "PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD"
              }
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 720,
              "Height": 480,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "H_264",
                "H264Settings": {
                  "InterlaceMode": "PROGRESSIVE",
                  "NumberReferenceFrames": 3,
                  "Syntax": "DEFAULT",
                  "Softness": 0,
                  "GopClosedCadence": 1,
                  "GopSize": 90,
                  "Slices": 1,
                  "GopBReference": "DISABLED",
                  "SlowPal": "DISABLED",
                  "SpatialAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "TemporalAdaptiveQuantization": "ENABLED",
                  "FlickerAdaptiveQuantization": "DISABLED",
                  "EntropyEncoding": "CABAC",
                  "Bitrate": 3000000,
                  "FramerateControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                  "CodecProfile": "MAIN",
                  "Telecine": "NONE",
                  "MinIInterval": 0,
                  "AdaptiveQuantization": "HIGH",
                  "CodecLevel": "AUTO",
                  "FieldEncoding": "PAFF",
                  "SceneChangeDetect": "ENABLED",
                  "QualityTuningLevel": "SINGLE_PASS",
                  "FramerateConversionAlgorithm": "DUPLICATE_DROP",
                  "UnregisteredSeiTimecode": "DISABLED",
                  "GopSizeUnits": "FRAMES",
                  "ParControl": "INITIALIZE_FROM_SOURCE",
                  "NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames": 2,
                  "RepeatPps": "DISABLED"
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            },
            "AudioDescriptions": [
              {
                "AudioTypeControl": "FOLLOW_INPUT",
                "CodecSettings": {
                  "Codec": "AAC",
                  "AacSettings": {
                    "AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix": "NORMAL",
                    "Bitrate": 96000,
                    "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                    "CodecProfile": "LC",
                    "CodingMode": "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                    "RawFormat": "NONE",
                    "SampleRate": 48000,
                    "Specification": "MPEG4"
                  }
                },
                "LanguageCodeControl": "FOLLOW_INPUT"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "FileGroupSettings": {
            "Destination": "s3://<MEDIABUCKET>/assets/VANLIFE/MP4/"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "CustomName": "Thumbnails",
        "Name": "File Group",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "RAW"
            },
            "VideoDescription": {
              "Width": 720,
              "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
              "Height": 480,
              "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
              "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
              "Sharpness": 50,
              "CodecSettings": {
                "Codec": "FRAME_CAPTURE",
                "FrameCaptureSettings": {
                  "FramerateNumerator": 1,
                  "FramerateDenominator": 1,
                  "MaxCaptures": 1,
                  "Quality": 80
                }
              },
              "AfdSignaling": "NONE",
              "DropFrameTimecode": "ENABLED",
              "RespondToAfd": "NONE",
              "ColorMetadata": "INSERT"
            }
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "FileGroupSettings": {
            "Destination": "s3://<MEDIABUCKET>/assets/VANLIFE/Thumbnails/"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "AdAvailOffset": 0,
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "EMBEDDED",
        "FileInput": "s3://rodeolabz-us-west-2/vodconsole/VANLIFE.m2ts"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Of course I am open to Bucket policy suggestions also if public access can be limited to the following 'folders' within this bucket.

```
<BUCKET>/videos 
<BUCKET>/encoded-video/mp4
<BUCKET>/encoded-video/poster
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following policy (not tested):

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Sid":"PublicAccessToFolders",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal":"*",
            "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/videos/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/encoded-video/mp4/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/encoded-video/poster/*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

More info about how Amazon authorize bucket access is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-s3-evaluates-access-control.html), and few policy examples are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. I've avoided this particular route because it doesn't apply ACL to each individual item. Therefore I think the content of the bucket that is public can be listed. My route would avoided any mass listing of the public items.

Comment: AWS does not recomend object ACL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-alternatives-guidelines.html Why not apply permissions at bucket/foilder level?  All files in those folders should have similar permissions, right?

Comment: Yeah, they should, ok thankyou for the reference link. 
If I apply this policy can some just visit the /videos/ URL and it list all its content to be scraped or viewed? Or does each item have an individual unique URL that can only be viewed if requested directly?

Comment: They need to exact URl, the policy do not allow to list bucket content, for that they need to have `s3:ListBucket` . See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html